# Crosstab using multi-element calculation

Tags: pandas, numpy

I would like to create a crosstab from a dataframe `df`, comparing each record of `df` to each other, i.e. pairwise, and calculate one number from several elements of the rows of `df`. As an example, let's take the following dataframe and calculate the (squared) distance between the points:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Point": ["A", "B", "C"], "x": [10, 20, 30], "y": [1, 2, 3]})

df["XX"] = 1

result = (
    df.merge(df, on="XX")
    .assign(distance=lambda d: (d["x_x"] - d["x_y"]) ** 2 + (d["y_x"] - d["y_y"]) ** 2)
    .loc[:, ["Point_x", "Point_y", "distance"]]
    .pivot(index="Point_x", columns="Point_y")
)
```

yielding the desired result:

```
        distance       
Point_y        A  B   C
Point_x                
A              0  5  20
B              5  0   5
C             20  5   0
```

Is there a better way to do this without resorting to adding a dummy field `XX` and merging on it? I tried multiple variations of

```
df = df.drop("XX", axis=1)

result = pd.crosstab(index=df["Point"], columns=df["Point"])
```

with `values=` and `aggfunc=` parameters, but to no avail. Possibly there is also an easier way using numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### "cross" merge

Assuming 1.2.0+, you can avoid the dummy `XX` column by merging with [**`how="cross"`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

> `cross`: creates the cartesian product from both frames, preserves the order of the left keys (*new in version 1.2.0*)

```py
(df.merge(df, how="cross")
   .assign(distance=lambda d: (d["x_x"] - d["x_y"]) ** 2 + (d["y_x"] - d["y_y"]) ** 2)
   .loc[:, ["Point_x", "Point_y", "distance"]]
   .pivot(index="Point_x", columns="Point_y"))

#         distance          
# Point_y        A    B    C
# Point_x                   
# A              0  101  404
# B            101    0  101
# C            404  101    0
```

#### numpy broadcasting

You can do the pairwise calculations in numpy by using singleton dimensions (`None` or [**`np.newaxis`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis)):

```py
x = (df.x.values[:, None] - df.x.values) ** 2
y = (df.y.values[:, None] - df.y.values) ** 2
pd.DataFrame(x + y, index=df.Point, columns=df.Point)

# Point    A    B    C
# Point               
# A        0  101  404
# B      101    0  101
# C      404  101    0
```

#### scipy squareform

If you compute a vector of pairwise values (e.g., result of [**`pdist`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)), you can use [**`squareform`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) to crosstab the vector:

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform, pdist
pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df[["x", "y"]]) ** 2), columns=df.Point, index=df.Point)

# Point      A      B      C
# Point                     
# A        0.0  101.0  404.0
# B      101.0    0.0  101.0
# C      404.0  101.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

As another option, using `euclidean_distances` from `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

euclidean_distances(
    df[['x', 'y']],
    df[['x', 'y']], squared=True)
```

Output:

```
array([[  0., 101., 404.],
       [101.,   0., 101.],
       [404., 101.,   0.]])
```