# How to crosstab distance in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my Input

```
City    Logitude    Latitude
A              2           2
B              5           6
C              8           10
```

Here's my Output, calculation using Pythagoras formula

```
      A      B     C
A     0      5    10
B     5      0     5
C     10     5     0
```

I'm only using Euclidian distance, write formula directly in formula still fine

Comment: use `geopandas` module

Comment: @eshirvana I'm only using euclidian distance, write formula directly in formula still fine

Comment: then implement the `euclidian distance` method and use `apply()` on your df , there are tons of implementation of that function if you google

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crosstab using multi-element calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67207841/crosstab-using-multi-element-calculation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a matrix of longitude and latitude only, then you can use `eucalidean_distance` function from the `scikit-learn` library.
You can later convert the result to data frame, add indices, etc.

```py
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

X = data.set_index("City")
euclidean_distances(X)
```

```py
array([[ 0.,  5., 10.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  5.],
       [10.,  5.,  0.]])
```